# Using ASIHTTPRequest to upload file to S3 with Content-MD5 header

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, md5, asihttprequest

I've had success using ASI to upload files to S3.  However, I'm having trouble getting upload to work when setting the 'Content-MD5' header value with an MD5 hash of the file I'm uploading.  I'm using the ASIS3ObjectRequest:addRequestHeader message to set the header value.  The failure that I get back is a 403 with the message:

Request failure: Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=2 "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." UserInfo=0x5ec210 {NSLocalizedDescription=The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.}

The odd thing is that I verified my hash value by uploading the file successfully without the Content-MD5 header and then checked the ETag for the file and the hash that I was trying to use for upload matches the ETag value!  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: May I ask why you are not using the AWS iOS SDK?  Also, I'm sure you are aware that ASIHttpRequest is no longer being supported.

Comment: I am aware of this.  Unfortunately I'm locked in to using this API for the time being.

Comment: Note: Some of the AWS forum comments suggest that the MD5 hash should be base64 encoded.  Attempting to base64 encode the hash yields the same error response.